# Linking errors when adding LibXML2 to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to add [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) to my c++ project in visual studio but when I attempt to build the project I get about 30 or so linking errors like the following

[image]

I know this is a pretty vague question, but can anyone point out what direction I should look to solve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you pointed the linker to the `libxml2.lib` file?

In Visual Studio it can be done in the project properties -

`Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`.

The path for the lib file can be specified in -

`Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`.

Comment: I had not done that, but after doing that I get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt you downloaded the libxml2 for linux not for windows, please double check that.

Comment: It is the libxml2 for windows.  the documentation keeps pointing back to the main site (linux) so that is what I linked too.

Answer (score 0):

In

Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

you have to add the

**.dll.a**

files ONLY, no .a, .dll or .la files.

Then in the execution directory, the .dll files must be present. (Or SymLink'ed.)

Comment: Linker error messages include:

libxml2.a : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __ms_vsnprintf
libxml2.a : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ms_vsnprintf

also:
___chkstk_ms
__imp_recv
__imp_select
__imp_WSAGetLastError
__imp_closesocket
__imp_socket
__imp_ioctlsocket
__imp_connect
__imp_getsockopt
__imp_htons
__imp_send
__imp_WSACleanup
__imp_WSAStartup
__WSAFDIsSet
WspiapiGetAddrInfo
WspiapiFreeAddrInfo
__imp_getsockname
__imp_bind
__imp_listen
__imp_gethostbyname